# How can I view all Wi-Fi network names (SSIDs) in my area?

Tags: macos, mac, wifi

I live in an area dense with Wi-Fi coverage. Eight SSIDs show from my menu bar dropdown, but I know there are more. Where can I view a full list of networks in my area? (I'm on a 2011 MacBook Air running 10.8, but it'd be nice to know in general.)

Answer (score 11):

There is a program you can run in terminal.

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
```

Update for 2021:  This command still works (as written) in OS 11 Big Sur.

Comment: Using built-ins is always preferred to third party, IMO.

Comment: Alternatively (on Mountain Lion), for a built-in GUI tool you can run the Wireless Diagnostics.app in /System/Library/CoreServices. You'll need to type an administrator password to run it. Ignore the window that appears and select Window > Utilities from the menu bar and click the Wi-Fi Scan tab (or press ⌘ + 2). It also gives you a few other handy utilities like performance monitoring etc.

Answer (score 5):

Get a copy of  [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net). That should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Nice one is the [NetSpot app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netspot-wifi-survey-wireless/id514951692?mt=12). Simple application to locate and visualize wi-fi spots.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **Wireless Diagnostics** application (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Wireless Diagnostics.app`). Go to the `Window` menu and choose `Scan`.